# C++ program crash when using auto_ptr or delete an array

Tags: c++, windows, gcc

I'm using g++ (with cygwin) under Windows. When I use auto_ptr or delete an array, my program crashes.
Those are two examples, which crash when running. I don't get any compile errors.

gcc version is 5.2.0-1.

I compile it with
`g++ -O3 -g0 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++14 -MMD -MP -MF"src/PtrTest.d" -MT"src/PtrTest.o" -o "src/PtrTest.o" "../src/PtrTest.cpp"`

Example 1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
int main() {
    std::auto_ptr<int> test1(new int);

    return 0;
}
```

Example 2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 4> *a = new std::array<int,4>;
    delete a;

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: "crash" as in? What does gdb say?

Comment: Note that in C++11 std::auto_ptr is deprecated and has been replaced by std::unique_ptr

Comment: gdb says:
[New Thread 96.0x1bdc]
gdb: unknown target exception 0xc0000139 at 0x7ffc6efec4e0

Comment: Same problem when using unique_ptr. But I don't have problems with that when using MS Visual Studio instead of g++.

Comment: Code is fine. Something else is wrong. If you can both give us a compiler command that actually produces an executable and not .o files, as well as perhaps reproduce your issue in an online compiler like ideone or coliru, then we can help you.

Comment: I tried MinGW and that worked well. I guess, it's some kind of problem with my gcc installation.